# Exclude from recent not working if hard recent button pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to remove my activity from a recent list when it closed. I am using activity tags

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:noHistory="true"
```

This is working fine on all devices but the devices have a hard View Recent Button (Right most button). When I click on this button, recent activity still shows up in the list. Whereas when I pressed the home button first (middle button) and then the recent apps button (right most button), the app does not show up in the list.

Comment: @Bilal did you found any solution for this?